# Accessing Internet Explorer with Shdocvw results in UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: c#, internet-explorer

I'm working on a portion of an application that has a 'finder' tool that allows the user to drag and drop a finder onto an application or internet explorer web browser so that our program can locate it and do what it needs to do. This portion of the application was not under any active development for the last few years (last time I believe IE 7 was the latest browser), but it has worked for IE 9 and below. Starting at IE 10 we get problems, and I specifically am using IE 11.

The following code locates the different Internet explorer windows (including tabs) and file explorer windows. We made a quick VB script for extra testing -

```
dim objShell
dim objShellWindows

set objShell = CreateObject("shell.application")
set objShellWindows = objShell.Windows

if (not objShellWindows is nothing) then
WScript.Echo objShellWindows.Count

for each win in objShellWindows
wscript.Echo TypeName(win)
WScript.Echo win.LocationUrl
WScript.Echo win.LocationName
WScript.Echo win.HWND
next

end if

set objShellWindows = nothing
set objShell = nothing
```

The above code will execute without error, and it gives the URL and title bar name of all the tabs we have open.

Below is our C# code. It attempts to get the main IE window (not the tab). `this.Handle` is the handle of this main IE window that the finder tool gets when the user drops it. We're attempting to iterate through the open windows and find the Internet Explorer window that the user selected. This particular snippet is changed slightly from our original implementation, but the end result is the same. As soon as it hits `test = window.Item(i)` it throws a `UnauthorizedAccessException`.

```
 ShellWindows windows = null;
 IWebBrowser2 shellWindow = null;
 IHTMLDocument2 actualDoc = null;

 Type shellApplicationType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Shell.Application");
 Shell32.Shell shellInterface = (Shell32.Shell)Activator.CreateInstance(shellApplicationType);
 windows = (ShellWindows)shellInterface.Windows();
 bool found = false;
 for (int i = 0; i < windows.Count; i++)
 {
     try
     {            
         object test;
         try
         {
             test = windows.Item(i); //Exception here
             shellWindow = (IWebBrowser2)test;
         }
         catch
         {
         }
         if (shellWindow != null && (IntPtr)shellWindow.HWND == this.Handle)
         {
            //the rest of the code gets the correct tab from the main IE window
```

This is the original unedited code from when we first revisited this portion of the program.

```
ShellWindows windows = null;
IWebBrowser2 shellWindow =null;
IHTMLDocument2 actualDoc = null;

windows = new SHDocVw.ShellWindowsClass();
bool found = false;
for (int i = 0; i < windows.Count; i++)
{
     try{
         shellWindow = windows.Item(i) as SHDocVw.IWebBrowser2; //Exception here
         if (shellWindow != null && (IntPtr)shellWindow.HWND == this.Handle)
         {
```

I would also like to note that instead of a `for` loop I have tried a `foreach` loop that followed this syntax

```
foreach(IWebBrowser2 browser in windows)
```

and

```
foreach(InternetExplorer browser in windows)
```

In those instances, the loop skips over the IE window.

I have looked at IE's security settings. I have disabled Enhanced Protection Mode and allowed cross domain. There does not seem to be a lot of information on this issue, and every approach we try seems to always end up with an `UnauthorizedAccessException`.

Edit: In response to Hans answer, I do not have any anti malware running on this machine. It is a virtual machine with windows 7 that has the latest SP and updates (no microsoft security essentials). I tried running the app on a 32 bit machine with similar settings and it also failed. After testing it on IE 11, I uninstalled IE 11, rebooted, tried IE 10 (it failed, same error), uninstalled IE 10, rebooted, tried IE 9, and it worked without making any other changes to the system.

Here is the SSCCE as requested by Hans. This code actually works on my target machine. I will return to this post in the next day or two while I handle other tasks that require my attention.

I build this as a 32 bit console app, and ran it on a 64bit machine.

```
using System;
using SHDocVw;
using mshtml;

namespace GetBrowserSSCCE
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ShellWindows windows = null;
            IWebBrowser2 shellWindow = null;

            windows = new SHDocVw.ShellWindowsClass();
            for (int i = 0; i < windows.Count; i++)
            {
                try
                    {
                    shellWindow = windows.Item(i) as SHDocVw.IWebBrowser2;
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Window Found. HWND: {0}\nName: {1}", shellWindow.HWND, shellWindow.Name));
                }
                catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("UnauthorizedAccessException caught. Exception Text: " +ex.Message);
                }

            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't reproduce the C# problem. What does the following code do: `dynamic app = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Shell.Application"));foreach (dynamic window in app.Windows) { Console.WriteLine(window); }` ?

Answer (score 4):

That this fails in your C# program but not when you run it from the VBScript interpreter points *strongly* to an environmental problem.  Both use the exact same shell interface.  The specific exception (underlying error code is 0x8007005) has been reported before on the interwebs but never diagnosed.

First thing you should focus on whenever you have an environmental problem, particularly the kind associated with access rights, is the anti-malware installed on the machine.  Disable it and try again.

Second one you should focus on is a quirk associated with ShellWindows, it doesn't just enumerate Internet Explorer windows but also Windows Explorer windows.  You've been looking at having sufficient access to IE but that isn't enough, this code can also fail if you happen to have an Explorer window opened and there's an access problem with the explorer.exe process.  Do note that your Activator.CreateInstance() method call is not equivalent to the VBScript code, Activator.GetObject() is.  So your changes would actually make the problem worse if this is underlying problem.

Third detail that's worth checking is the bitness of your process.  By default, your VBScript code will run in the 64-bit script interpreter on a machine that boots the 64-bit version of Windows.  But the default setting for a C# project is to run in 32-bit mode.  Right-click your EXE project, Properties, Build tab and tinker with the Platform target setting, the 'Prefer 32-bit' checkbox if you see it.  This is *not* an explanation for the error code, it can however affect the effectiveness of anti-malware to intrude.

Comment: I am testing this on a virtual machine that has no anti-malware so that should not be an issue. I will install the program on a 32 bit virtual machine and see if I still run into any issues, and if not then I believe you are correct about the bitness being the problem. Edit: I don't believe the windows explorer windows are the problem, I noticed that they were enumerated as well, but the algorithm correctly skips over them (I was using WinSpy++ to keep track of window handles)

Comment: Unfortunately, the 32 bit machine still ran into the same problems. I think it's worth to note, that after testing it on IE 11, I uninstalled IE 11, rebooted, tried IE 10 (it failed, same error), uninstalled IE 10, rebooted, tried IE 9, and it worked without making any other changes to the system.

Comment: Please post an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/), I cannot repro this problem at all, even with an elevated Windows Explorer instance, using Windows 8.1 and IE11.

Comment: I will post the SSCCEE above, however when I tested it, the program worked. So now I'm thinking there's something about our implementation that isn't compatible with IE 10+. I will have to revisit this thread a in the next couple days, I have other tasks that are requiring my attention but in my free time I will continue exploring possibilities.